# Is there any reason to memoize Redux action creators in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, memoization

My coworker has stated that articles he's found have pointed to performance increases when memoizing Redux action creators in React, but I've not found anything that supports that and I can't really see how it would help.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```js
const Component = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
    const actions = useMemo(() => ({
        updateField: (...args) => dispatch(updateField(...args)),
        blurField: (...args) => dispatch(blurField(...args)),
        clearAllFields: (...args) => dispatch(clearAllFields(...args)),
    }), [dispatch]);
    
    return (
        <button onClick={actions.clearAllFields}>Clear</button>
    )
}
```

Does this make sense and I just don't see why? The dispatch function should never change over the course of the component's lifecycle, and neither should the action creators, so there shouldn't be any increase in the number of rerenders whether you memoize the action creators or not.

**Note**: this is unrelated to the topic of memoizing Redux state.

Comment: Just a point of clarity, the "action creators" in your post are specifically the `updateField`, `blurField`, and `clearAllFields` actions, but what you are memoizing are the callback handler functions that are passed as props. Markerikson's answer is sufficient and I totally agree, all the extra code and extra strain on readability/maintainability isn't work the few extra ticks of "performance" gained. We don't memoize functions for performance, we memoize them to be stable references that are passed as props (*which isn't the case here in your example*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no meaningful point to it, *especially* in this particular example.

Yes, strictly speaking, creating a function instance has a non-zero cost, same as `i++` has a cost.

Now, calling `useMemo` *is* creating *one* function instance on every render, and very strictly speaking, creating *one* instance is cheaper than *three* instances for `updateField/blurField/clearAllFields` every time.

But it's not meaningful enough to be worth worrying about.

Additionally, there's no benefit in trying to maintain the *same* function references here.  The child element is a `<button>`; it's not wrapped in `React.memo()` to avoid re-renders; and there's no further nested child components, so there's no extra cost of React recursing through a deep tree to render it.

I actually covered some of those points in my post [A (Mostly) Complete Guide to React Rendering Behavior](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/#how-new-props-references-affect-render-optimizations).

So, it's not *wrong* to call `useMemo` here, but it's absolutely not *necessary*, and I really wouldn't bother with it in this case.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! I was hoping that my intuition was on the right track; I'll need to take some notes on your blog post, there's a lot of nuanced behavior when it comes to React rendering that I have yet to fully grasp lol